# Does the color of refractive medium affects the color of refracted light?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Imagine if I have a red colored prism that splits white light ray into its seven components, would the red component be affected by the red color of the glass material of the prism in any which way? I imagine that the red color of the glass material is nothing but red light reflected towards our eyes, would this reflected(or refracted) light interfere with the red component of split light ray before reaching our eyes?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The only effect that the red color would have would be to attenuate all the colors that are not red.  With white light in, you'll still get a spectrum out, but the blues and greens will be dimmer than they would be with a clear prism.

(The positions of the colors might be shifted by a very small amount because absorption comes with a small change of refractive index.)

Comment: I could not understand the things mentioned in brackets, please explain further.

Comment: Light of different colors come out of the prism at different angles.  That's why we see them separate.  They come out at different angles because the refractive index for each color is different.  If the material had the same refractive index for all colors, they would all come out at the same angle, and they would not separate.  A red prism absorbs some blue light (and some green, etc).  A material that absorbs at a color (e.g. by the addition of a dye) will have its refractive index shifted from a similar material that does not absorb. So the colors will come out at slightly shifted angles.